scrolling down in google search reivews
I'd like to extract the title, address and average_review from each restaurant in Google Search. Extracting these elements has worked well so far. Additionally, I'd like to extract the last review date from all reviews, so I want the crawler to load all reviews and extract the last element. In order to load all the review dates, the crawler needs to scroll down in the defined range (Part of the Page) and more reviews will automatically be displayed. However, so far the crawler is extracting all the data it needs, but only the review dates that are displayed at the beginning. I've tried a lot of things but I don't know what else to do.
I really appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance,
Paolo
I've tried various things like implementing a counter to calculate how many times new reviews need to be loaded and many different ways of scrolling with defined heights, just iterating through the reviews also didn't work, calculating new scroll height and comparing with last scroll height also didn't work, I've also tried changing the order but it didn't change anything.
This is my current code:
import csv
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException
from time import sleep


class GetDataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "getdata"
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.google.com/']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.google.de/search?q=z%C3%BCrich+restaurants&cr=countryCH&sca_esv=50eae9b505889d1f&sca_upv=1&biw=1051&bih=932&tbs=ctr%3AcountryCH&tbm=lcl&ei=_4UNZvaoNdz_7_UP7sSHUA&ved=0ahUKEwi2pK7PvaaFAxXc_7sIHW7iAQoQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=z%C3%BCrich+restaurants&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWxvY2FsIhN6w7xyaWNoIHJlc3RhdXJhbnRzMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABEiEDlDbCFjbCHAAeACQAQCYAfgBoAGZA6oBBTIuMC4xuAEDyAEA-AEBmAIDoALhA8ICChAAGIAEGIoFGEPCAgQQABgewgIGEAAYBRgewgIGEAAYCBgemAMAiAYBkgcFMS4xLjGgB7AT&sclient=gws-wiz-local#rlfi=hd:;si:;mv:[[47.3905548,8.5475649],[47.3602911,8.5219958]];tbs:lrf:!1m4!1u3!2m2!3m1!1e1!1m4!1u2!2m2!2m1!1e1!1m4!1u1!2m2!1m1!1e1!1m4!1u1!2m2!1m1!1e2!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e1!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9'
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.csvfile = open('titles.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
        self.fieldnames = ['title', 'average_review', 'address', 'reviews']
        self.writer = csv.DictWriter(self.csvfile, fieldnames=self.fieldnames)
        self.writer.writeheader()
        self.options = Options()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
        
    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.url
        self.driver.get(url)
        self.scrape_page()
    
    def scrape_page(self):
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        last_restaurant_count = None

        while True:
            parent_divs = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div > div.rllt__details')
            current_restaurant_count = len(parent_divs)

            # If the current restaurant count is the same as the last restaurant count, break the loop
            if last_restaurant_count == current_restaurant_count:
                break

            for i in range(current_restaurant_count):
                try:
                    # Re-find the divs and get the current div
                    div = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div > div.rllt__details')[i]

                    # Extract title, average review, and address for each restaurant
                    title = div.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.dbg0pd > span.OSrXXb').text
                    average_review = div.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.z3HNkc').get_attribute('aria-label')

                    # Click on the div to reveal the address
                    div.click()
                    sleep(2)  # Wait for the address to load

                    # Extract address
                    address_element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.LrzXr'))
                    )
                    address = address_element.text

                    # Click on the "Rezensionen" tab
                    try:
                        reviews_tab = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@data-index="2"]'))
                        )
                    except TimeoutException:
                        reviews_tab = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@data-index="1"]'))
                        )
                    reviews_tab.click()

                    sleep(2)  # Wait for the reviews to load

                    # Scroll to load more reviews
                    self.scroll_to_load_reviews()

                    # Extract reviews
                    review_dates = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.y3Ibjb')
                    reviews = [review_date_element.text for review_date_element in review_dates[:50]]

                    self.writer.writerow({'title': title, 'average_review': average_review, 'address': address, 'reviews': reviews})

                    # Go back to the restaurant list page
                    self.driver.back()
                    sleep(2)  # Wait for the page to load

                except (StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException) as e:
                    print(f"Error: {e}")
                    continue
            last_restaurant_count = current_restaurant_count  

    def scroll_to_load_reviews(self):
        try:
            reviews_container = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#akp_tsuid_34 > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > g-sticky-content-container > div > block-component > div > div.dG2XIf.knowledge-panel.Wnoohf.OJXvsb > div > div > div > div.ifM9O > div > div > div.hjPqT4GkFUQ__expanded > g-flippy-carousel > div > div > ol > li:nth-child(3) > span > div > div > div > div.EfDVh.wDYxhc.NFQFxe > c-wiz > div > div.aSzfg > div:nth-child(1)')
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", reviews_container)
            sleep(2)  # Wait for the reviews to load
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error scrolling to load reviews: {e}")

    def close(self, reason):
        # Close the CSV file when the spider is closed
        self.csvfile.close()
        # Close the driver when the spider is closed
        self.driver.quit()



